# Screen Size of Smart_TV_Emulator_5_1 on virtualBox

Tags: sdk, virtualbox, emulation, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to test my apps on the 2014_Smart_TV_Emulator_5_1 running on virtualBox. My problem is The screen of the TV is half crossed and I cannot see anything.
So, the screen is not ideal and I don't know how to set the right size. 
Normally in virtualBox you use guest additions, but c'mon this is a TV and just nothing happens when I try to mount Guest Additions. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. 
I should just to press (Host Key) + L 
To change the mode of the screen.